# find a word in a sequence of alphabet chars

Tags: regex

Using [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com), I need to find de word banana in a sequence of alphabet characters that also do not include the word ana.

I have tried the following
banana((?!ana).)*

and it does not work in the following sentence
alfabetwithsbananaandnotana

It highlights everything from semana until ana. I am new with regex, can anyone help out?

Comment: I do not see semana in that string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\b(?![a-zA-Z]*ana[a-zA-Z]*ana)[a-zA-Z]*banana[a-zA-Z]*\b
```

See demo **[here](http://regexr.com?37cpt)**.